# PHP Getting a variable with json from Blockcypher

Tags: php, json

Example: https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/172tcvQ2TNn4gWJx8g3TsaqbWcyJuk7jNZ

Hi everybody!

With each transaction I have a new BTC address and I need to get the value of "spent" (unconfirmed_txrefs -> spent in the example above). So I wrote this code, and I'm not sure what's wrong with it (I'm not a programmer).

Part of the code relevant to the question:

```
<?php

include_once("JsonRPC2Client.php");

class Invoice {

public function update() {

    $address = $this->_data['btc_address']; //get the current btc address, works

    $contents = file_get_contents("https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/$address");

    $sp = json_decode($contents);

    $sp->spent+0;
```

I want $sp to be true or false.

Comment: Try `$sp->unconfirmed_txrefs->spent`.

Comment: It didn't work. Tried both $sp->unconfirmed_txrefs->spent; and $sp->unconfirmed_txrefs->spent+0;